# Angular 2/4 : Mobile Number Auto Detection not working in Angular2/4

Tags: ios, angular, mobile, mobile-safari, autolink

**Feature : "By default, Safari on iOS detects any string formatted  like a phone number and makes it a link that calls the number."**

- Working as expected Environments  : Plain HTML and Angular 1.x.
- We do the same implementation in another angular 2 application . this feature is not working as expected.
- **Current behavior :** In Angular2/4 - Safari on iOS does not detect any string formatted like a phone number and it does not make it a link(iOS Devices).
- **Expected behavior :** By default, Safari on iOS detects any string formatted like a phone number and makes it a link that calls the number.

**Please go with the below JS Fiddle URL:** (Please open this URL in iOS Devices we will not see this auto detection feature)

```
   <a href="https://jsfiddle.net/1hk7knwq/3752/">https://jsfiddle.net/1hk7knwq/3752/</a>
```

Comment: `<a>` tag supports phone numbers `<a href="tel:555-555-5555">`

Comment: yeah that will work... but our requirement is different...We want the Mobile Number to be clickable  and  Mobile Linking : It is default behavior of iOS Devices. It detects the phone numbers automatically when we do a long press on the number it shows bottom sheet which has options to make a call.
This Feature is present only in iOS - Safari